# Which is true about paying bills?

Tags: phrase-usage

which one is correct

- Payment with cryptocurrency
- Payment in cryptocurrency
- Payment using cryptocurrency

which one is correct

- Settlement with cryptocurrency
- Settlement in cryptocurrency
- Settlement using cryptocurrency

Comment: I think 'with' is better option.

Comment: This needs more context.

Comment: Please list what you think is correct and why, and what research you've done.

Comment: @stangdon This is a title without before or after

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All are equally correct and mean the same thing. It is purely a matter of personal taste which governs which one you use.

Answer (score 0):

Let us try using other types of money in place of cryptocurrency. Let us use "coins" and "paper money". Which ones do sound right to you?

> Payment with coins
> Payment in coins
> Payment using coins
>
> Settlement with coins
> Settlement in coins
> Settlement using coins
>
> Payment with paper money
> Payment in paper money
> Payment using paper money
>
> Settlement with paper money
> Settlement in paper money
> Settlement using paper money

Personally I would use "Payment with cryptocurrency" and "Settlement in cryptocurrency".